# Error while installing scrapy on mac OSX 10.11.1

Tags: python, macos, scrapy, osx-elcapitan

I am new to scrapy and i tried installing scrapy on mac using this command

```
sudo pip install scrapy
```

and i got this error:

> Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/private/tmp/pip-build-lpJzV8/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-H3llSf-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-lpJzV8/lxml

Can someone help?

Comment: What would happen if you do `sudo pip install lxml`?

Comment: Do you have the command line tools installed? You need them to build certain python modules.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if you have command line tools installed as @birryree suggested. If not, you could fire up the terminal (type terminal in spotlight) and type `xcode-select --install`. Then run `pip` again. By the way, I tried installing just now and it installs fine.